# How do I import user roles with feeds?

Tags: 9, feeds

I created a CSV file with a column "Roles" and values like `role_a, role_b`, where `role_a` is the machine name of the role.

However, when I try to import the role in my feed, I get an error that `role_a` and `role_b` do not exist-- but they definitely do exist on my site.  How can I import roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Feeds module can only handle a single input value.  To input multiple values (such as multiple roles), you need to modify the data before Feeds processes it.

You can do this with the [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module.

1. Install the Feeds Tamper module.
2. Go to the **Tamper** tab of your feed type admin screen (`/admin/structure/feeds/manage/MY_FEED_MACHINE_NAME/tamper`.
3. For the Roles field, click **Add Plugin** and add the `Explode` plugin with the default settings.
4. Next, click **Add Plugin** again and add the `Characters to trim` plugin with the default settings.

If you don't complete step 4, then when Feeds Tamper explodes the string into multiple values, your second value will be  `role_b` (with a space in front), which will cause assignment of that role to fail.